# I want to copy only the last one of the text in the input box using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The logic for copying the value of the input box when clicking the input box is as follows.

```js
<input type="text" value="{{p.filename}}" id="file_{{p.id}}" size=100 onclick="copy_for_file_name({{p.id}})">

function copy_for_file_name(id){
    var copyText = document.getElementById("file_"+id);
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
    document.execCommand("copy");
    // alert("copy is completed")
}
```

At this time, if the value of the input box is

```
challenge/templates/challenge/challenge_list.html
```

Can the code be modified so that only challenge_list.html is copied 
when the onclick event is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way how you could do it:

```js
function copy_for_file_name(id){
    var copyText = document.getElementById("file_"+id);
    // get the original text value
    const org = copyText.value;
    const match = org.match(/\/([^/]+?\.\w+)\s*$/);
    if(match) {
      // if found file name, replace with it temporarily
      copyText.value = match[1];
    }
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
    document.execCommand("copy");
    // restore the text value
    copyText.value = org;
    alert("copy is completed")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="challenge/templates/challenge/challenge_list.html" id="file_1" size=100 onclick="copy_for_file_name(1)">
```

Comment: it's perfect answer it's good solution thanks for let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy only the filename (without the directory name), try using the following code:

```js
var fileName = ((filePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1)<filePath.length)?(filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1)):filePath
```

It uses the last index of a forward slash to construct a substring (starting at the character after the last slash, to the end of the string). If there aren't any slashes, it returns the original string.

#### How to use:

Just set `filePath` to the path you want to modify, and it sets `fileName` to the resulting filename. It's one line, and it can be placed anywhere in your code.

#### Function version:

```js
var getFilename = function (path) {return (((path.lastIndexOf("/")+1)<path.length)?(path.substr(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1)):path)}
```